# Update coloumn in a table

Tags: sql-server

I want to update a col and add 5 min to a column according to batches.

Let say Current snapshot:

```
Time                      | batch
2015-03-26 08:20:54.077   | 1
2015-03-26 08:20:54.077   | 1 
2015-03-26 08:20:54.077   | 1
2015-03-26 08:20:54.077   | 1
2015-03-26 08:20:54.077   | 1
2015-03-26 08:22:54.077   | 2
2015-03-26 08:22:54.077   | 2
2015-03-26 08:22:54.077   | 2
2015-03-26 08:22:54.077   | 2
2015-03-26 08:24:54.077   | 3
2015-03-26 08:24:54.077   | 3
```

After update:

```
My_Time                      | batch
2015-03-26 08:25:54.077   | 1
2015-03-26 08:25:54.077   | 1 
2015-03-26 08:25:54.077   | 1
2015-03-26 08:25:54.077   | 1
2015-03-26 08:25:54.077   | 1
2015-03-26 08:30:54.077   | 2
2015-03-26 08:30:54.077   | 2
2015-03-26 08:30:54.077   | 2
2015-03-26 08:30:54.077   | 2
2015-03-26 08:35:54.077   | 3
2015-03-26 08:35:54.077   | 3
```

On the basis of my current queryit is not achived.Plz guide.

```
UPDATE table_name SET My_Time = DATEADD(minute, 5, My_Time);
```

It is adding time on the basis of current time of delay but how can it be update on the basis of previous batch?

Comment: can you explain how is the time 2015-03-26 08:30:54.077 for batch 2 after update

Comment: @ughai it is dependent on the time after the update of batch 1

Comment: @ughai Let say I have to add 5 min to My_time so initially the 5 min are added to first batch and on the basis of 1st batch time next batch is modified for next 5 min..

Comment: would the third batch depend on the intial batch 2 time + 5 mins or new batch 2 time update + 5 mins. can you include another batch 3 in input and the output

Comment: @ughai yes that what i meant.. thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

try this

**Sample Data**

```
DROP TABLE snapshot 
CREATE TABLE snapshot (time DATETIME,batchid INT)

INSERT INTO snapshot VALUES('2015-03-26 08:20:54.077', 1),
('2015-03-26 08:20:54.077', 1 ),
('2015-03-26 08:20:54.077', 1),
('2015-03-26 08:20:54.077', 1),
('2015-03-26 08:20:54.077', 1),
('2015-03-26 08:22:54.077', 2),
('2015-03-26 08:22:54.077', 2),
('2015-03-26 08:22:54.077', 2),
('2015-03-26 08:22:54.077', 2),
('2015-03-26 08:26:54.077', 3),
('2015-03-26 08:26:54.077', 3)

SELECT * FROM snapshot;
```

**Query**

```
DECLARE @increment_by_mins INT = 5

UPDATE snapshot
SET time = updated_time
FROM snapshot
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT batchid, DATEADD(MINUTE, @increment_by_mins * orderedid,ISNULL(LAG(time) OVER(ORDER BY batchid),time)) updated_time
    FROM
    (
        SELECT MIN(time) time,batchid,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY batchid ASC) as orderedid
        FROM snapshot
        GROUP BY batchid
    )updated_snapshot
)updated_snapshot
ON updated_snapshot.batchid = snapshot.batchid


SELECT * FROM snapshot;
```

**Edit**

Based on your answer, It seems what you are trying to do is similar to what I initially proposed.
Since all your time is based on the lowest time of the initial batch, you just need a `DENSE_RANK()` and a `DATEADD` to accomplish what you need.

```
DECLARE @initialtime datetime;
SELECT TOP 1 @initialtime = time 
FROM snapshot
ORDER BY batchid,time;

DECLARE @minutes INT = 5
;WITH CTE AS 
(
SELECT time,batchid,DENSE_RANK()OVER(ORDER BY batchid ASC) oid
FROM snapshot
)
UPDATE CTE
SET time = DATEADD(minute,@minutes * oid ,@initialtime)

SELECT * FROM snapshot
```

Comment: This is not what is being asked

Comment: @t-clausen.dk based on the the comment from xyz _Let say I have to add 5 min to My_ime so initially the 5 min are added to first batch and on the basis of 1st batch time next batch is modified for next 5 min._  and the time in output for batch 2 the time is dependent on the first My_Time

Comment: the third batch should depend on the time for the second batch, in this solution will depend of first batch instead

Comment: this looks better, but I dont think you should multiply batchid by 5

Comment: @ughai This is giving me wrong result for thrid batch

Comment: @ughai posted my own answer..but this functionality be achieved without creating temporary table?

Comment: @ughai Changes in the third batch would be ('2015-03-26 08:26:54.077', 3),
('2015-03-26 08:26:54.077', 3) to ('2015-03-26 08:24:54.077', 3),
('2015-03-26 08:24:54.077', 3) and expected output would be time in minutes as 25,30 and 35 for batch 1,2 and 3 respectively.Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @tempTable TABLE 
( 
     ID int IDENTITY(1,1), 
     batchid INT
)  
     INSERT INTO @tempTable 
     SELECT distinct batchid FROM snapshot 
     declare @CuentdateTime Datetime =null
     set   @CuentdateTime =(select top 1  time from snapshot) ;
     DECLARE @tempTablecount INT 
     DECLARE @count INT = 1 
     SELECT @tempTablecount = COUNT(*) FROM @tempTable 
     WHILE(@count<=@tempTablecount) 
     BEGIN 
         select  @CuentdateTime =   DATEADD(MINUTE, 5, @CuentdateTime); 
           UPDATE snapshot SET time = @CuentdateTime where batchid=(select batchid FROM @tempTable   where id=@count)                      
     SET @count = @count + 1 
     END
```